# Deploying django app. on heroku (gunicorn, wsgi issue)

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I have updated my django application from 1.4.1 to 1.6.5 so far it works properly locally.
I am now trying to deploy it to heroku, so I am trying to run the wsgi.py file, but whenever I run it with the following in the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application
```

It starts and tells me where its listening, but if I try to access the address given, I get the following error:

```
23:51:27 web.1  |   File "~/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 8, in <module>
23:51:27 web.1  |     from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
23:51:27 web.1  | ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.contrib.auth.middleware:"cannot import name ContentType"
```

I tried to use the following in the Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py run_gunicorn
```

It ran, BUT this command has been deprecated.

Comment: Have you updated your requirements.txt file with to state it needs `django==1.6.5`? Otherwise it will probably respin the dyno with your past version

Comment: just 'web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi'

Comment: Yes I have updated my requirements.txt file. I tried using just 'web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi' still the same error

Answer (score 0):

It related with `'ContentTypes'` model . Can you inspect the database .. it having the table called `'contenttype'`. If it's there then delete it. Before doing the migration again .. make sure `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`